# How to extend a Vec<String> as HashMap value?

Tags: vector, hashmap, rust

I have a `HashMap<String, Vec<String>>`. I cannot figure out how to update the value by growing the `Vec`.  I thought the following would work:

```
fn add_employee(mut data: HashMap<String, Vec<String>>) -> HashMap<String, Vec<String>> {
    loop {
        println!("Please enter the name of the employee you would like to manage.");

        let mut employee = String::new();

        io::stdin().read_line(&mut employee).expect(
            "Failed to read line",
        );

        let employee = employee.trim();

        let mut department = String::new();

        println!("Please enter the name of the department you would like to add the employee to.");

        io::stdin().read_line(&mut department).expect(
            "Failed to read line",
        );

        let department = department.trim();

        data.entry(department.to_string())
            .extend(vec![employee.to_string()])
            .or_insert(vec![employee.to_string()]);
    }
}
```

but it instead gives the error

```
error: no method named `extend` found for type `std::collections::hash_map::Entry<'_, std::string::String, std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:27:14
   |
27 |             .extend(vec![employee.to_string()])
   |              ^^^^^^
```

Comment: The [HashMap `Entry` API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html) does not provide `extend`, but `Vec` does. You want to manipulate the value in the entry if it exists. Have a look at [`HashMap::entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
use std::collections::hash_map::Entry;

match data.entry(department.to_string()) {
    Entry::Occupied(mut entry)  => { entry.get_mut().push(employee.to_string()); },
    Entry::Vacant(entry)        => { entry.insert(vec!(employee.to_string())); },
}
```

- If the key exists, get a mutable reference on the value and add the new string,
- Else, create a new vector and insert it in the hashmap.

All this information is in the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html).

Comment: Is there a performance difference using this `match` approach versus the answer I posted?

Comment: I *think* it is the same. Do some benchmark to be sure. However, you must replace `extend` with `push` as I did.

Answer (score 2):

After thinking about the entry API a little more I came up with the following solution:

```
let val = data.entry(department.to_string())
                .or_insert(vec!());

        val.extend(vec!(employee.to_string()));
```

Comment: It should always be written as `vec![]` to remain idiomatic.

Comment: Better: `data.entry(department.to_string()).or_insert(vec![]).push(employee.to_string());`

Comment: @Boiethios -- thanks.  I had tried that but calling the `push` before `or_insert`, which did not work.  Don't know why I didn't realize the order should be as you have written.

Comment: Sure, I did not noticed the swap of methods ;)